# Why does socket.io not join a given room?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having problems when I try to join a socket to a room. The name of the room is the socket.id and it is assigned when it is connected. But when this happens it doesn't join to room. What could be the error?

Client code:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on("connect", function() {
    socket.emit("joinRoom", socket.id);
});

socket.on("agentMessage", function(msg) {
    $('#messages').append("<div class='agent-messages'><p>" + msg + "</p></div>");
});
```

Server code:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
   let roomID;

    socket.on("joinRoom", (socket_id) => {
        roomID = socket_id;
        socket.join(roomID);
        socket.to(roomID).emit("agentMessage", "Welcome!");
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        socket.leave(socket_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: In case your code is not just for an example, I also wanted to point out that socket.io already is adding each user to a room based off of their socket id! 

So if you need another named room the question/answer still works, but if you are quickly trying to send a message to one user, simply use:  io.to(socket.id).emit("hello!");   

or in this specific case:  io.to(socket.id).emit("agentMessage", "Welcome!");

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `client` is actually joining the `room`, but it is not sending the `message`. As you are sending `message` from the `server` side you cannot send it using the `socket`, as `socket` represents a `client` connection and cannot throw `events` on behalf of `server`. You have to use

```
  io.to(roomID).emit("agentMessage", "Welcome!");
```

as io represents a server instance and can throw events on behalf of server(actually it is the server).
[image]

[Reference](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

Comment: Thanks dude, that's is the problem!

Comment: If this solved your problem, mark the answer as correct so that it will help others too.